# android: In-app Purchases, How exactly sell stickers in IM my app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have chat app, that is published and worked... I want to sell stickers for the users.
I have read the documentations of google Developers, but I got confused!
considr I have my oun graphics (png Files):

- Where to put the sticker? (ImageView)?
- How to transfer the Purchased Sticker to the user?

I know how to Enable the In-app Purchases in my app, but Don't know how to practice real selling... (on test)[all the stips on the documents I did] but the problem is when I whant to sell real sticker, where to put the sticker? in which activity? how to let the Purchase user to use it, and pervent other from doing.

I have not write code to provide here, I realy don't know how to start...

Any Idea?!